# How can I get reliable jump-to-definition for Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I tried the Elixir plugin for Jet Brains, and two of them for VS Code, but so far none of them reliably takes me to the definition of functions and modules. Apparently part of the reason is because elixir-lsp cannot handle things inside of `scope` blocks (https://github.com/elixir-lsp/elixir-ls#known-issueslimitations).

Comment: I can confirm that the intellij plugin works, the problem was with latest versions of IDE, intellij always makes breaking changes and it takes some time to update the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a stop-gap solution for this using Universal Ctags.

On Mac:

```sh
brew install --HEAD universal-ctags/universal-ctags/universal-ctags
/usr/local/bin/ctags --exclude=node_modules -R .
```

Add something like this to your ~/.vimrc:

```
set tags=tags,./tags,../tags,../../tags,../../../tags,../../../../tags,../../../../../tags
```

Then fire up Vim on some Elixir files and use ctrl-] to jump to definitions, ctrl-O to jump back.

To make life easier, I added this Makefile target:

```sh
echo '
.PHONY: tags
tags: 
        /usr/local/bin/ctags --exclude=node_modules -R .
' >> Makefile
```

The PHONY line tells Make to always run the command even if there is already a tags file.

VS Code has a plugin called ctagsx that works well with these tag files. I'm using it together with the ElixirLS plugin and that seems to be working so far.

So far I have not found a way to make JetBrains/Intellij IDEs work with these tag files.

Comment: Note: it's handy to also unpack the Elixir source distribution into a subdirectory and rerun `make tags` so you can jump to the definitions of core modules and functions as well.