# How can I use tags files generated by ctags within Intellij or other JetBrains IDEs?

Tags: intellij-idea, elixir, jetbrains-ide, ctags

I'm using a language (Elixir) that doesn't have strong jump-to-definition support in its JetBrains plugin. If I generate tags using Universal Ctags, it works great within Vim ([How can I get reliable jump-to-definition for Elixir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65781075/how-can-i-get-reliable-jump-to-definition-for-elixir)), but I want to use my JetBrains IDE for its other features.

Is there a way to tell JetBrains to use the generated `tags` file when jumping to definitions?

I looked for plugins matching "ctags" in my JetBrains IDE but found nothing.